# Rails 5.2 Is it possible to use routes to assign enum values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If for example I have a User model with two user roles:

```
enum role: {regular: 0, admin: 1}
```

Is it possible to pass the user role via the link_to helper?  Here would be an example:

```
<%= link_to "New Admin User", new_admin_user_path %>
```

I realize this is pretty far-fetched as a concept, but I would like to leave the controller as generic as possible.

Comment: I would ask if the complexity is worth it compared to just having a select on the form of a single controller. The answer depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say is pretty far-fetched but possible. First, create a route using `scope` and `:as` for each role:

```
User.roles.keys.each do |role|
  scope role, as: role do
    resources :users
  end
end
```

Your routes will be:

```
Prefix           Verb   URI Pattern         Controller
new_regular_user GET    /regular/users/new  users#new
new_admin_user   GET    /admin/users/new    users#new
```

This allows you to

```
<%= link_to "New Admin User",   new_admin_user_path %>
<%= link_to "New Regular User", new_regular_user_path %>
```

The URI Pattern contains the `role` and `user` model, so in your controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    role, model = request.path.split("/")[1, 2]  # ["", "admin", "user"]
    @user = model.classify.constantize.new(role: role)
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you need the whole `model.classify.constantize` buisness. As I far as I understood the question there is a single user class. Only the value of the `role` attributes changes.

Comment: `User.new(role: role)` should be sufficient.